# $f \in L^1(- \infty , + \infty)$ , Find the limit $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{{+ \infty}}_{- \infty} \frac{f(x)e^{nx}}{1+e^{nx}} dx $

Tags: real-analysis

$f \in L^1(- \infty , + \infty)$ , Find the limit $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{{+ \infty}}_{- \infty} \frac{f(x)e^{nx}}{1+e^{nx}} dx $

**My Attempt**

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{{+ \infty}}_{- \infty} \frac{f(x)e^{nx}}{1+e^{nx}} dx =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{{+ \infty}}_{- \infty} \frac{f(x)}{1+e^{-nx}} dx $$

Define $g_n(x)= \frac{f(x)}{1+e^{-nx}}$, The integrable function $f(x)$ dominates all $g_n(x)$ for all $x \in (-\infty, + \infty)$ due to the simple fact that $1+e^{-nx} > 1$ for all $n$ and all $x \in (-\infty, + \infty)$. Now using the Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence theorem we have
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{{+ \infty}}_{- \infty} \frac{f(x)}{1+e^{-nx}} dx &= \int^{{+ \infty}}_{- \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{f(x)}{1+e^{-nx}} dx \\
&= \int^{0}_{- \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{f(x)}{1+e^{-nx}} dx + \int^{{+ \infty}}_{0} \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{f(x)}{1+e^{-nx}} dx 
\end{align}
$$ Since $f \in L^1(- \infty , + \infty)$ we conclude that $f$ is finite a.e. on $(- \infty , + \infty)$ and hence $$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{f(x)}{1+e^{-nx}} = 0 \ \ \ \ if \ \ x\in (-\infty,0)$$ and $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{f(x)}{1+e^{-nx}} = f(x) \ \ \ \ if \ \ x\in (0,+\infty) $$ Therefore $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{{+ \infty}}_{- \infty} \frac{f(x)e^{nx}}{1+e^{nx}} dx = \int^{+\infty}_{0} f(x) dx$$

I would be thankful if you tell me whether this approach is correct or not.  Thanks !

Comment: Looks perfectly good to me...

Comment: @IgorRivin Thank you !!!